# How to select a single digit from a MULTI-VALUE field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, multivalue

I have the following table with '' as a special character:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 1312 |
| 3 | 315 |
| 4 | 1613 |
| 5 | 15311 |

I want to select only those records where `Column 2` has `3` between special characters.
I have used a built-in function of my DB `fn_SplitOneValue` but it selects `3` and `13` both. Please help!

Comment: Show your function code, and show your desired results. And seriously consider normalising your database. This form of storage will cause you issues for the life of the product.

Comment: It wouldn't @DaleK, but `WHERE Column2 LIKE N'%3%'` might (the special characters are U+F8FD).

Comment: But you also have to deal with the case that `3` is first or last in the delimited list - @nauman - this is not in first normal form. These values should be stored in a table with 10 rows not 5  for current data. (1 row for Column 1 = 1, 3 rows for  Column 1 = 5 and 2 rows each for the rest)

Comment: Yes @Martin, you are right it's not normalized. But it is what it is since I'm not the DB admin.

Comment: You need to show the query that you used. You are probably doing a `LIKE`, try using `=`

Comment: `WHERE CONCAT(N'', Column2, N'') LIKE N'%3%'` should do what you need with no need to call any split function

Comment: If you are determined to use a "multi-valued" field why not use an industry standard like JSON?  You gain inbuilt functions and simpler support in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
begin try 
create table #test ([Column 1] int, [Column 2] nvarchar(100))

insert into #test ([Column 1], [Column 2])
values (1, '13')
    ,(2, '1312')
    ,(3, '315')
    ,(4, '1613')
    ,(5, '15311')
end try
begin catch
end catch

select *
from #test
where charindex('3',[column 2],0)>0
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have a try catch around your creat table statement?

Comment: It's a secret :D